# Adding scoring profile in a search query using Azure Cognitive Search client library for .NET

Tags: azure, search, azure-cognitive-services

I have a indexer created in Azure cognitiveSearch, I have also created a default scoring profile in azure portal for that indexer. Now I want to use the client to set up a tag based scoring profile where I want to boost the score where

```
"func1-val1", "func2-val2", "func3-val3"
```

.These 3 values are defined as a function in my azure portal default scoring profile.

In my code I am calling the search method of this client with the scoring parameters passed as option values

```
ASP.NET (C#)

Copy
SearchOptions options = new SearchOptions
            {
                SearchMode = SearchMode.All,
                Filter = filters,
                Size = 10000,

            };


            options.GetType().GetProperty("ScoringParameters").SetValue(options, 
                new List<string> { "func1-val1", "func2-val2", "func3-val3" });


            options.GetType().GetProperty("ScoringStatistics").SetValue(options, ScoringStatistics.Global);

            options.GetType().GetProperty("ScoringProfile").SetValue(options, "DeliveryScoringProfile");

//calling the azure search client library .NET method 

searchClient.search(searchquery,options)
```

But my scoring profile is not working as my results are not getting boosted up, If I directly hit the indexer in azure portal with a query then I am getting the result in the right order. But when I am trying to hit it from the library it's not working,

can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set all of these values while initializing your SearchOptions:

```
SearchOptions options = new SearchOptions
{
  SearchMode = SearchMode.All,
  Filter = filters,
  Size = 10000,
  ScoringProfile = "DeliveryScoringProfile",
  ScoringStatistics = ScoringStatistics.Global,
  ScoringParameters = new List<string> { "func1-val1", "func2-val2", "func3-val3" })
};
```

Besides that, everything you're doing looks like it should work as expected.